# Self-timer on Canon 5d Mark III?

Tags: canon, canon-5d-mark-iii

How do I use the self-timer on the Canon 5D Mark III?

Comment: This is well described in the camera instruction manual. Is there something in particular there that you don't understand or is not working for you?

Comment: I've voted to close this as "unclear what you're asking". The basic question is, of course, simple — but it's unclear what _particular_ trouble you're having with something that seems straightforward on the face of it (and at the very least easy to look up). Please help by providing further context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Press the **AF-Drive** button.
- Turn the **Quick Control** dial (the large dial on the back of the camera) until the 2-second or 10-second self-timer symbol appears in the lower right on the small LCD screen on top of the camera body.
- Take the picture by pressing the **Shutter** button. The camera will start counting down and then take the picture after the 2 or 10 second interval.

It is all on page 113 of this version of the [5D Mark II *Instruction Manual*](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/42005.pdf). Some versions of the manual have an extra page and this is on page 114 of those versions.